# Is there any EVM debugger with a flexible UI layout available as of 2021?

Tags: contract-debugging

Remix debugger seems to be pretty mature. But, its web-based interface makes it impossible to shuffle the block around. For example, I want to move the "Stack" section to the right sidebar so that it can take up a longer/wider space; thus fitting a deeper stack without needing to scroll the page. However, Remix doesn't allow me to rearrange the UI according to my convenience. The other debuggers I found in Reddit seem to be either abandoned or in the infancy. Hence, those are not usable at all. Is there any EVM debugger available at the moment which provides the same feature as Remix, but the UI is a bit more flexible?